# Are any Boeing 720s still flying?

Tags: aviation-history, boeing-720

A [Boeing 720](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_720) looked like a 707 but was the size of a 737. I flew in one in 1961. I did not travel regularly until 1970 but I do not remember ever seeing a 720 again. Was it intended to have limited production? Are there any 720's still flying?

Comment: From a distance the B-720 looked exactly like a B-320. Both aircraft were powered by four P&W JT-3B engines; however, the B-720 engines were de-rated to 17,000 lbs. of thrust from  the 18,000 lbs. for the B-320. Additionally, the MTOW of the B-720 was 235,000 lbs. vs. 336,000 lbs for the B-320.  The B-720 was a real "hot rod" when it came to performance.

Comment: The last one I saw was parked on the ramp at Shannon in Ireland, if anyone's looking to take pictures.

Comment: 'the size of a 737' threw me a bit, so I looked at the Wiki article. 'A 720 is a slightly shortened 707' would be a more accurate description IMO.

Answer (score 10):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_720), no. The last one was retired in 2010.